# Tweetie plugin don't work in localhost

Tags: php, jquery, localhost, twitter-oauth, wampserver

I use Tweetie plugin [Link](https://github.com/sonnyt/Tweetie).
It works good when upload the site, but don't work in my localhost.
I use wamp server on windows 8.1

```
<div class="twitter-feeds">
    <div class="tweet"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tweetie.js"></script>

<script class="source" type="text/javascript">
    $('.twitter-feeds .tweet').twittie({
        username: 'NawaraGFX',
        list: 'c-oo-l-e-s-t-nerds-i-know',
        dateFormat: '%b. %d, %Y',
        template: '<strong class="date">{{date}}</strong> - {{screen_name}} {{tweet}}',
        count: 1
    }, function () {
        setInterval(function() {
            var item = $('.twitter-feeds .tweet ul').find('li:first');

            item.animate( {marginLeft: '-220px', 'opacity': '0'}, 500, function() {
                $(this).detach().appendTo('.twitter-feeds .tweet ul').removeAttr('style');
            });
        }, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: any error on `console`

Answer (score 0):

Use your codes after `$(document).ready(function(){ ..... });` :

```
<script class="source" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {

    $('.twitter-feeds .tweet').twittie({
        username: 'NawaraGFX',
        list: 'c-oo-l-e-s-t-nerds-i-know',
        dateFormat: '%b. %d, %Y',
        template: '<strong class="date">{{date}}</strong> - {{screen_name}} {{tweet}}',
        count: 1
    }, function () {
        setInterval(function() {
            var item = $('.twitter-feeds .tweet ul').find('li:first');

            item.animate( {marginLeft: '-220px', 'opacity': '0'}, 500, function() {
                $(this).detach().appendTo('.twitter-feeds .tweet ul').removeAttr('style');
            });
        }, 5000);
    });

});
</script>
```

Also use developers tool(chrome) or firebug(firefox extension) and check the console tab to check the error.

Comment: I try it, but don't work also. I remove $(document).ready because I use jQuery at the end of bode.

Comment: No console error. The same code work when upload it to the web server

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is to the domain which is **localhost** 
i got this problem too with twitter and facebook plugins

so the only solution here is to change your host file

> C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\

[this video may help](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1N6c3p4IVY)